# How to pass a char buffer as codes to call on exec?

Tags: c, exec, posix

I'm using `exec`xx to execute some executables, but for security reason (and other reasons), I hard coded the binary as HEX digitals into my caller's codes as a `const unsigned char[]`.

For example:

```
unsigned char code[] = {
    0x7f,0x45, 0x4c,0x46, 0x01,0x01, 0x01,0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00, ...
}
```

and some how execute it like this: `exec(code, argv[])`...

But I searched for a while, and found all exec families accept either a path or a `File` struct.

So is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: The `Exec` family of function can only execute external programs, not arbitrary bytes of code. It's not even guaranteed that the data in in a memory segment that is marked as executable. If it was (in an executable memory segment) you could run it directly without any of the `exec` functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use `mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)` to push some assembly codes into an executable memory and run it before, do you mean I can use the same way here? I think an executable is a lot different than assembly codes (for example dynamic loading or crash handling)

Comment: Oh it's a complete ELF executable image? Then no that won't work. You need to save it to a (temporary) file that you pass to `exec`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes it is, totally a normal elf executable.

Comment: I think this solution is awesome, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Save the image to a (temporary) file which you can then use with one of the standard `exec` functions; Or
2. Create a pipe which you send the image to, and at the other end use `fexecve` to execute from the pipes read-end descriptor.

Comment: I'm afraid the 2 solution won't work, I tried for a while, and the errno said I don't have the permission... I guess path like "/proc/self/fd/95" is just not valid.

Comment: @psionic12 Maybe I should have added a disclaimer that I've never tried it and don't actually know if it would work... :) And reading [the POSIX `exec` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fexecve.html) it seems that the descriptor must be "executable". It might be possible to do using `fcntl` or similar?

Comment: You can do 2 with a memfd, but not with a pipe.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's an even better idea. :)